# MacOS & fontspec: font-not-found when using "defaultfontfeatures"

Tags: fontspec

This is similar to, but not, to me, the same as, several other questions here. My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[DejaVu]
  {
    UprightFont = DejaVuSerif.ttf,
    ItalicFont = DejaVuSerif-Italic.ttf,
    BoldFont = DejaVuSerif-Bold.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont = DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
  }
\setmainfont{DejaVu}
\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

Running this with `xelatex` produces

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "DejaVuSerif.ttf" cannot be found.
!
...
```

If I replace `\setmainfont{DejaVu}` with `\setmainfont{DejaVuSerif.ttf}`, everything works correctly, which tells me that my setup is okay, and the font can be found by `fontspec`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you’re trying to run `\setmainfont{DejaVu}` instead of `\setmainfont{DejaVuSerif}`? (DejaVu comes in both serif and sans-serif varieties — `DejaVu` is simply not sufficiently descriptive.)

Comment: @Mico In my document, I don't need sans serif fonts, so I use the simpler form. In any case, using `DejaVuSerif`doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: On MacOS using a font name rather than the file name requires that the OS “sees” the font; I.e., it appears in FontBook.

Comment: In terms of the syntax I wouldn't have expected that to cause a problem. Hmm...

Comment: @HerbSchulz You can use `defaultfontfeatures` or a `.fontspec` file to provide a nicer name, avoiding the need to use the file name or install the font.

Comment: I have the  Dejavu fonts in my ~/Library/Fonts folder so they show up in Font Book. If I use the name `Dejavu Serif' (without the quotes), which is what Font Book calls the font, I have no problem compiling the sample document.

Comment: Sigh... I just noticed the file names in the default font features. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in fontspec, thanks for spotting it. I haven't tried to analyse this yet but the following workaround fixes it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[DejaVu]
  {
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont = DejaVuSerif,
    ItalicFont = DejaVuSerif-Italic,
    BoldFont = DejaVuSerif-Bold,
    BoldItalicFont = DejaVuSerif-BoldItalic
  }
\setmainfont{DejaVu}
\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

(I suspect my code thinks that because `.ttf` wasn't part of the `[DejaVu]` name it shouldn't try to add an extension, but then there's probably an incorrect normalisation and the `.ttf` is stripped off when it shouldn't be.)

Comment: This has been added to the issue tracker: https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/334

Comment: Please let me know if I can test anything or provide more information.